# How to optimally serve static files with REST API back-end on Heroku

Tags: rest, heroku, proxy, nginx

This question may be a bit subjective but I think will offer some valuable concrete information and solutions to proxying to heroku and debugging latency issues.

I have an app built using Sinatra/Mongo that exposes a REST API at api.example.com. It's on Heroku Cedar. Typically I serve static files through nginx at www and proxy requests to /api through to the api subdomain to avoid cross-domain browser complaints. I have a rackspace cloud instance so I put the front-end there temporarily on nginx and setup the proxy. Now latency is horrible when proxying, every 3 or 4 requests it takes longer than 1 minute, otherwise ~150ms. When going directly to the API (browser to api.example.com) average latency is ~40ms. While I know the setup isn't ideal I didn't expect it to be that bad.

I assume this is in part due to proxying from rackspace - server may well be on the west coast - to heroku on amazon ec2 east. My thought at the moment is that getting an amazon ec2 instance and proxying that to my heroku app would alleviate the problem, but I'd like to verify this somehow rather than guessing blindly (it's also more expensive). Is there any reasonable way to determine where the long latency is coming from? Also, any other suggestions as to how to structure this application? I know I can serve static files on Heroku, but I don't like the idea of my API serving my front-end, would rather these be able to scale independently of one another.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Heroku to run your API, what I'd suggest is putting your static files into an [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket, something named 'myapp-static', and then using [Amazon Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) to proxy your static files via a DNS CNAME record (static.myapp.com).

What's good about using S3 over Rackspace is that:

- Your files will be faster for you to upload from Heroku, since both your app and storage are on the same network (AWS).
- S3 is built for serving static files directly, without the overhead of running your own server proxying requests.

What's good about using Cloudfront is that it will cache your static files as long as you want (reducing multiple HTTP requests), and serve files from an endpoint closest to the user. EG: If a user in California makes an API request and gets a static file from you, it will be served from them from the AWS California servers as opposed to your East Coast Heroku instances.

Lastly, what you'll do on your application end is send the user a LINK to your static asset (eg: http://static.myapp.com/images/background.png) in your REST API, this way the client is responsible for downloading the content directly, and will be able to download the asset as fast as possible.